# EndeavourOS/Arch Linux broken after power off. NVMe drive not detected by any method

Tags: linux, boot, mount, arch-linux

After a forced power off, my system looks broken.

The OS was installed in a BTRFS system.

Booting EndeavourOS normally will hang with:

```
“A start job is running for /dev/disk/by-uuid/…” (forever)
```

`cat /etc/fstab` command simply outputs `static information...`

Booting with a live iso and tried everything (`lsblk`, `blkid`, `fdisk`, `parted`, `/proc/mounts`, and `/etc/fstab`), the NVMe drive is not shown (as if it did not exist) by any method.

I could copy the outputs here, but there is no point, as it is very clear the drive is not detected.

Since it is not detected, all solutions with mounting methods i found online look useless, as I would not be able to manually `mount` / `fsck` / `chroot` a drive that is a total ghost.

Is there an alternative?

Comment: From your description it appears the SSD is dead. To prove that point, or to *try* to salvage data, put the drive in another machine, either internally or in an external enclosure. N.B., **If** there is valued data on the dive, do not try this yourself -- a commercial data recovery service *might* be able to salvage *some* data for a fee (check cost before proceeding).

Comment: Could be the NVMe is dead. Try reseating it.

Comment: @Giacomo, what do you mean?

Comment: Try taking out the NVMe drive and putting it back in again. Reseating it.

Comment: Oh, I see. Will try this

Comment: Tried reseating as suggested by @Giacomo, but still got nothing. I suspect the drive is dead. So sad... Lost a long non-commited edit to a sensitive repository :(

Comment: @GuedesBF Try taking the NVMe drive out and putting it in an external NVMe enclosure. Might be a case where the NVMe controller on your system is dead, but it can be read in an external enclosure.

Comment: Will try that. Thank you very much, @Giacomo

Comment: Giacomo, Is the controller being desde on my system a hardware thing?

Comment: I sought professional assistance. They were able to recover all the data with some specific software. The NVMe drive is in good health, and I am using it as an external drive with an USB-C enclosure now. Still cant boot with it. The internal NVMe was replaced and after a fresh install, everything is working fine. I had the dotfiles saved on Dropbox, so setup was smooth. Thanks, everyone.